# Extract the line from sentence using first and end word

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace the line from a sentence with white-space. Here it is:

```
<p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:10pt; line-height:115%; font-size:12pt">
    <span style="font-family:Calibri;font-weight:bold; color:#ff0000">Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2016 Aspose Pty Ltd.</span>
</p>
```

So I want to extract the line from 'Evaluation' word to 'Ltd.' word with blank space and get the rest of the line. Something like this:

```
<p style="margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:10pt; line-height:115%; font-size:12pt">
    <span style="font-family:Calibri; font-weight:bold; color:#ff0000"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Will this always be a `<p><span>` and text in it ?

Comment: Are you looking for a .NET regular expression solution? Or Java, Perl, etc?

Comment: @AndyLamb .net regex

Comment: You want to remove Inner html of every span or remove every line starting with'Evaluation' and ending with 'Ltd'. Buddy, you need to set some rules here.!

Comment: This will capture the required string:- https://regex101.com/r/zP0tO0/1

its not clear what you want but you can check :- http://ideone.com/QLGw1g

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using javascript like

```
document.getElementbyId("your span id").innerHtml = 
                   "what text you want here";
```

Comment: I'm using this in c#

Comment: OP is specifically looking for C# Regex solution not  a java-script solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the train, on my phone, so the example below might not be 100% syntactically correct, but you can use the Regex.Replace method.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "Evaluation.*Ltd\.", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution it works

```
Match Line = Regex.Match(str, @"Evaluation\s*(.+?)\s*Ltd.");
str = str.Replace(Line.ToString(), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HtmlAgilityPack to load the Html file.

Open the file:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(myHtmlString);
```

Then remove the nodes:

```
foreach(var descendant in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").ToList())
descendant.Remove()
```

Then get the string the represent the HTML file:

```
string htmlWithoutStyle = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

For more examples kindly refer the link:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net/